# Is there a way to provide content for Endeca Workbench tool?

Tags: stop-words, endeca, endeca-workbench

I'm not being able to find a way to provide input data, like stop words and redirects info, into Endeca Workbench tool by API or XML file, if there's such possibility . Help?

Comment: This depends on the version of Endeca you are using. For example in 11.3 the redirects are now maintained in `json` format. Which version are you looking for?

Comment: it's an older version, sadly =( Endeca Workbench version is 2.1.2

Answer (score 0):

For stop words you can try this method.
http://edgydebug.blogspot.fr/2017/06/endeca-configure-stop-words.html